# Interacting with plain-TeX programs

Tags: tex-core

Is it possible to read from stdin in plain TeX? I have seen that it is possible in LaTeX with `\typein` (See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311910/interactive-console-at-terminal-evaluating-commands)), however, this is unavailable in TeX.
Are there any alternatives?

An MWE in *LaTeX*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \typein[\name]{What is your name?}%
    Hello, ``\name''
\end{document}"
```

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdfl

Comment: Check `latexdef @xtypein` (the definition of typein)…

Comment: @TeXnician `\@xtypein` doesn't seem to be defined, I'm running my program using `tex`

Comment: Yes, of course you are using tex, but if you wanted to see what LaTeX does (in terms of TeX macros) it would be easiest to have a look at the LaTeX definition in latex.ltx or via latexdef…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `\read<number> to \foo` when the number doesn't correspond to an open input stream and the number is nonnegative, TeX will prompt you with

```
\foo=
```

The stream cannot be open if the number is greater than 15, so any integer from 16 up is good. If you use a negative number, the prompt is not shown, but TeX will wait for input nonetheless.

There's the problem of the trailing space, which comes from the end-of-line you insert by hitting Return. This can be solved by setting the end-of-line character to have category code 9.

```
\def\prompt#1{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=9 % ignore the end-of-line
  \read 20 to #1%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}

\prompt\foo

\show\foo
```

The console output is

```
\foo=xyz
> \foo=macro:
->xyz.
l.11 \show\foo

?
```

In the first line TeX prompts for `\foo`; I typed in `xyz` and Return. The output of `\show` tells us that there is no space. The grouping confines the change of category code. With the chain of `\expandafter` we are able to define `\foo` also outside the current group *before* closing it.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to `\write 18` for output, the following solved my issue.

```
\read 18 to \name
```

Content from stdin appears in `\name`, however a space appears on the end.